# How I can make discord.js bot statistics on website?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, discord.js

I have one short and probably easy question. So - how can I import bot stats to my website?

Mainly I mean the number of:

• users (`${client.users.cache.size}`),

• guilds (`${client.guilds.cache.size}`)

• channels (`${client.channels.cache.size}`).

I know that it can be done in a simple way on the basis of "information exchange" between files, but they must be for 1 VPS - I do not have such a possibility, unfortunately. Is there any other way? If so, how can I do it? (If someone already knows how to do it, I would like to ask for a "more" description of this issue, because I had no contact with the "information exchange" between the website and the bot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a REST Api for your bot that gives these stats to some API endpoint, and then request that API from your website using fetch.